# Frequency response simple equation

Tags: functions

I'm looking at answers to calculating the frequency response, but i don't understand one line. what are they doing to go from the first line to the second line?

[image: equation]

Comment: What is blocking you ? $e^{-ja/2}\, e^{ja/2} = 1$ for example

Answer (score 1):

They are drawing out a factor of $e^{-j\omega/2}$ from the expression inside the brackets,$$H(\omega)=0.5(1+e^{-j\omega})\cdot\frac{e^{-j\omega/2}}{e^{-j\omega/2}}=0.5e^{-j\omega/2}\Big(e^{j\omega/2}+e^{-j\omega/2}\Big)$$